# Role isnt getting recognised by discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', guildMember =>{
    let welcomeRole = guildMember.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === '820716669303128116');
 
    guildMember.roles.add(welcomeRole);
    guildMember.guild.channels.cache.get('821031990894788628').send(`Welcome <@${guildMember.user.id}> to our server!`)
});
```

Keep getting error = **"Supplied roles is not a Role, Snowflake or Array or Collection of Roles or Snowflakes."**

I have no idea as to what I did wrong. (The IDs are correct, btw)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use `Collection#get` instead of `Collection#find` if you're going to get roles by their id.

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', guildMember =>{
    let welcomeRole = guildMember.guild.roles.cache.get('820716669303128116');
 
    guildMember.roles.add(welcomeRole);
    guildMember.guild.channels.cache.get('821031990894788628').send(`Welcome <@${guildMember.user.id}> to our server!`)
});
```